# Angular 2 - Server responded file not found

Tags: angular, angular2-template

The only change i have done before my last successful run is, just added a parent folder "src" for app, but now browser console showing me below error --

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) src/app/app.module

and my main.ts file is

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from '../app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: where your main.ts file sits?

Comment: Could you give us a look at your folder structure?